# Problem with NodeJS Cron, double execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, discord.js

I have an issue with node cron.
In fact when I start this cron it works for about ~24h and after the cron runs twice and 3 times, etc etc.

Can you help me ?
Here is my npm cron package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Here is my code :

```
var Update = new cron('*/1 * * * *', async () => {
        function CheckReboot(){
            const date = new Date()
            if(date.getHours() === "16" || date.getHours() === "10"){
                if(date.getMinutes() <= 3){
                    return true
                }else{
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        if(CheckReboot()){return}

        const GET_API_Webservices = await API_Webservices()
        if(!GET_API_Webservices){
            return new Error("can't access to API Webservices (Refresh Staff en Ligne)")
        }
        const GET_API_Webservices_serveurs = GET_API_Webservices.serveurs

        if(GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[1].staffs_en_service === "[]"){
            if(!s1_cache.includes("Aucun")){Alert_ServerWithoutMods(1)}
            var s1_mod = ["Aucun"]
        }else{
            var s1_mod = JSON.parse(GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[1].staffs_en_service)
        }
        if(GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[2].staffs_en_service === "[]"){
            if(!s2_cache.includes("Aucun")){Alert_ServerWithoutMods(2)}
            var s2_mod = ["Aucun"]
        }else{
            var s2_mod = JSON.parse(GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[2].staffs_en_service)
        }
        if(GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[3].staffs_en_service === "[]"){
            if(!s3_cache.includes("Aucun")){Alert_ServerWithoutMods(3)}
            var s3_mod = ["Aucun"]
        }else{
            var s3_mod = JSON.parse(GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[3].staffs_en_service)
        }

        s1_cache = s1_mod
        s2_cache = s2_mod
        s3_cache = s3_mod

        const parsed_message = `@everyone\n**[STAFFS EN SERVICE]**\n\n- \`\` Serveur 1 - [${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[1].total_joueurs}/${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[1].slots}] (Admin : ${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[1].total_admins}) -\n-> ${s1_mod.join("\n-> ")}\n\n- \`\` Serveur 2 - [${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[2].total_joueurs}/${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[2].slots}] (Admin : ${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[2].total_admins}) -\n-> ${s2_mod.join("\n-> ")}\n\n- \`\` Serveur 3 - [${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[3].total_joueurs}/${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[3].slots}] (Admin : ${GET_API_Webservices_serveurs[3].total_admins}) -\n-> ${s3_mod.join("\n-> ")}`
        chan.fetchMessage("690357691364933646").then(m => {
            m.edit(parsed_message)
        })
    }, null, true)
```

This Cron is used to update a message on Discord which displays the administrators available on a game server and send DM to Moderators when there is not Staff, but somethings we receive the message twice or more times ...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am still reading your code but meanwhile, you can correct this mistake, this condition always returns false as getHours returns back number!

```
if(date.getHours() === "16" || date.getHours() === "10")
```

// updated

I do not think there is any problem with Cron just as I explained above, your **if statement** always returns back false that causes this line never returns:

```
if (CheckReboot()) {
    return
  }
```